# Emulate a USB camera with an IP camera for web conference

Tags: windows, networking, usb, webcam, ip-camera

Our office uses Cisco's WebEx for business web conferences and I want a camera with Pan/Tilt/Zoom for use in our board room.
Unfortunately WebEx only supports USB cameras (mainly those on the Windows HCL), but there are many IP cameras that are significantly less expensive than a USB cam with P/T/Z...

Is there any way to emulate a USB connection with an IP Camera so I can trick WebEx into using it?

Comment: Punch `WebEx "ip camera"` into your favorite search engine for links like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9TUrxlHZSU).

Comment: yeah - pretty much that.  I guess I need to find a camera that is supported by such drivers. Thanks